# need to revert to windows operating system ,but got stuck in ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, windows-10, system

i tried installing Ubuntu on my windows 10 acer PC and , when the installation process was done i was told to remove the USB drive and allow the PC to restart ; but to no avail , the pc got stuck on a boot loop because it couldn't repair the windows system automatically. i tried all sorts of videos on the subject , some of which made me use the command prompt and after every input of commands i either get this message ;*access denied, or the file specified is not found* so with no luck in the command prompt i tried a video that told me to change somethings in the bios and select f12 to go into the boot screen and with my USB still in the PC i booted Ubuntu through the boot manager , now i want to use windows 10 but don't know how to revert to my windows settings

Comment: Can you boot to any operating system at all?  What happens if you change boot priority in BIOS?  Did you disable all instances of "fast boot" and "fast startup" on your BIOS and Windows?

Comment: What boot options are available to you in BIOS?

Comment: You should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, same key you used to boot Ubuntu installer should show Windows as a boot option. You may need f8 to get into repair console, unless your install of Ubuntu erased Windows. You often need to turn fast start up off and use Windows tools to shrink NTFS partition. And with Acer you need to set "Trust". Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot
Have you updated UEFI?

Comment: i didn't have the option to boot into windows no matter what i did in the command prompt , hence why i went into the bios and disable the safe boot and turned the PC off the went to the boot manager screen using f12 , and I am there with my USB connect to the PC , the same USB in which i had the Ubuntu file , i was given the option to boot up the PC using the USB which had Ubuntu to boot  up the PC , and now I am  using Ubuntu operating system to interact with the internet

Answer (score 1):

Well, that can be done, sort of. No easy way :

- 1. Can you enter BIOS ?

  - 1.1 If you can :
    Do you have recovery or Windows installation media ?

    - If you have :

      - Change your boot order to boot from that media
      - Recover/repair your Windows boot partition find a way, somewhere)
    - If you dont :
      Go get it (somewhere)
  - 1.2 If you can't :

    - Plug off your hardisk, enter BIOS, change boot order, then go with (1.1)
- 2. Can you enter Windows after your boot partition recovered/repaired ?

  - 2.1 If you can :

    - Find your Windows boot partition location.
    - Recover/repair your linux bootloader (GRUP) / reinstall ubuntu (if your /home in the same partition with /root, they will completely destroyed).
    - Make sure GRUP overwrite Windows boot at same partition.
    - Make sure there no other GRUP installed in other partition. if there is another, find a way to delete it.
  - 2.2 If you cant :

    - Looks like some of your Windows system file missing. You need to repair or      reinstall Windows.
- 3. Your system will boot into GRUP >> Find Root location >> Load Ubuntu
- 4. If you choose Windows >> GRUP find Windows boot location >> Load Windows

There is another option, over that long way. Straight forward, repair your boot partition from GRUP command promt. But if you are linux newbie like me :) I dont recommend that. Trust me, I have tried it, hours of drama, wasting my time. Your Windows still there, not going anywhere, you just need find a way, so your system boot into there.